# How to report this bug?

Tags: 18.04

Most bugs are impossible to report. You have to have a package. Well, this is multiple packages, Ubuntu itself, and hardware/firmware related. How the heck do I file it? ubuntu-bug requires a single package. It's not automatically triggering the built-in Ubuntu bug reporter.

When I close the lid of XPS 9560, and wake up, a lot of stuff is wrong. The GUI will freeze and unfreeze every few seconds, as something is grinding it to a halt. The wifi can't reactivate. It can't even try to scan for networks, much less join one.

Here's recent dmesg output:

```
[43548.249307] ath10k_warn: 129 callbacks suppressed
[43548.249309] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.285609] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.316369] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.347057] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.382893] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.419305] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.455788] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.492277] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.523109] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43548.553793] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to wake target for read32 at 0x0003a028: -110
[43551.161054] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to read device register, device is gone
[43551.270391] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid c2f1d8ad-ba2b-4c87-a0e1-9dff072ac468)
[43551.270394] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[43551.270396] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[43551.270803] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[43551.271233] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[43551.271235] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: htt-ver 3.47 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[43551.271242] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to read firmware dump area: -28
[43551.271243] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[43551.417001] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43551.562682] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43551.708407] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43551.841610] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43551.975925] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43552.108938] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43552.254895] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43552.400652] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295
[43552.400689] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to reset chip: -5
[43552.400690] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Could not init hif: -5
```

Comment: I would report it again the kernel

Comment: But this still is related to 1 package: firmware-atheros  (WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 is probably the thing to go on). You probably need to turn off power management for the time being :)

Comment: How do I report it against the kernel or the firmware-atheros (WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1)?

If I ubuntu-bug, what's the argument afterward, and should it be kernel or firmware?